# Not allowed to load local resource: file:///

Tags: php, codeigniter

I have some images in a folder called "Slides" in my project; I am trying to access those images; but it gives me the following error:

```
Not allowed to load local resource: file:///C:/xampp/htdocs/MyProject/Slides/123_completed.jpg
```

where is "file://" coming from?! (Probably thats the problem!)

this is my method to scan the images in the folder called "Slides"

the following line of code is in my

```
$this->signage_Path = realpath(APPPATH . '../Slides');
public function get_Signage_Images() {
    $files = scandir($this->signage_Path);
    $newFiles = array_diff($files, array('.', '..'));
    $images = array();
    foreach ($newFiles as $file) {
        $ext = pathinfo($file, PATHINFO_EXTENSION);
        if ($ext == "jpg") {
            $images[] = array(
                'url' => $this->signage_Path.'\\'.$file,
                'thumb_url' => $this->signage_Path.'\\'.$file,
            );
        }
    }
    return $images;
}
```

If you need more clarification, please let me know which part!

Thanks

Comment: view-source, find the element that loads Slides/123_completed.jpg -- are you loading the page through a normal http://localhost url?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's probably coming from your `APPPATH` constant in `realpath()`. Should be more like `$this->signage_Path = 'MyProject/Slides'`, without `realpath()`. PHP cannot access a file that is not on a Server, without Client permission. Of course, I really don't know what your `sinage_Path` is supposed to be. This should just give you an idea of your problem.