# PHP XAMPP Server DOCUMENT_ROOT folder structure

Tags: php, xampp, document-root

So this is my first time creating a test site with xampp. I originally had all my php files in one folder and just recently decided to organize the data (yes, hindsight i should've started with an organized folder structure.) Anyways, I have my setup like this:

" [  ] " implies it is a FOLDER

Installed on my C:\ drive

```
[xampp]
└── [htdocs]
    └── [QMS]
        └── [rev3]
            ├── [css]
            ├── [js]
            ├── [DPU]
            ├── [login]
            ├── index.php
            ├── header.php
            └── config.php
```

In my "config.php" file I tried to define a root path (this may be the error):

```
$path = $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'] . "/QMS/rev3/";
```

.

Then in my header.php file I have:

```
<?php
require $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'] . "/QMS/rev3/config.php";
include $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'] . "/QMS/rev3/login/session.php";
.....
?>

HTML - located in the <head> section

<link rel='stylesheet' type='text/css' href='<?php echo $path . "css/searchBar.css"; ?>'/>
<link rel='stylesheet' type='text/css' href='<?php echo $path . "css/tables/filtergrid.css"; ?>'/>
<script type="text/javascript" language="javascript" src='<?php echo $path . "js/jquery.dataTables.js" ?>'></script>
<script type="text/javascript" language="javascript" src='<?php echo $path . "js/jquery.loader.js" ?>'></script>

... MANY OTHER scripts and stylesheets.
```

.
My index.php is:

```
require $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'] . "/QMS/rev3/header.php";
```

When I launch this in Chrome - I get the following errors for ALL of my scripts and stylesheets (19 errors total):

```
"NOT ALLOWED TO LOAD LOCAL RESOURCE  file///C:/xampp/htdocs/QMS/rev3/ ......etc..."
```

My site was working perfectly when all my files were in the same folder and I wasn't using SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'], but now I have no idea what to do...any advice?

.

Comment: Check your file permissions on C:/xampp, make sure the user group `Everyone` has read permission.

Comment: Where exactly are these permissions located?

Comment: Standard windows permissions. Right click the folder, go to properties and then select the security tab.

Comment: I changed permission for everyone to have full control of the C:\xampp folder and I still get the same error

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**NOT ALLOWED TO LOAD LOCAL RESOURCE**

The url you use in `<a>`, `<link>`, `<script>`, etc tags should be relative to the document-root, eg:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="/QMS/rev3/css/searchBar.css" />
```

Don't confuse *paths on disk* with *url's*, they're two completely different things :)

**Advise on determining the root path**

I recommend not to rely on the `$_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT']` variable, but determine the root-folder like this (in `config.php`):

```
define('ROOT_PATH', __DIR__);
```

You'll have a constant named `ROOT_PATH` which will contain `C:\xampp\htdocs\QMS\rev3` (without a trailing `/`).

Now you can do things like:

```
require ROOT_PATH . '/header.php';
```

The path in `ROOT_PATH` differs from the document-root. If you really want to use the document-root, do this (so that `ROOT_PATH` will then contain `C:\xampp\htdocs`):

```
define('ROOT_PATH', __DIR__ . '/../..');

# ...

require ROOT_PATH . '/QMS/rev3/header.php';
```

**Canonicalized absolute pathname**

It might be wise to use `realpath()` as mentioned by [Capsule](https://stackoverflow.com/users/181206/capsule) (expand all symbolic links and resolve references to `/./`, `/../` and extra `/` characters):

```
$rootPath = __DIR__ . '/../..';  # or just __DIR__
$realPath = realpath($rootPath);
define('ROOT_PATH', $realPath ?: $rootPath);
```

If `realpath()` fails to resolve the path it will return `false`, that's why there's a little check.

Comment: In your example, I'd use `define('ROOT_PATH', realpath(ROOT . '/../..'))` instead of `define('ROOT_PATH', __DIR__ . '/../..')`. No need to determine what's __DIR__ again and you don't want PHP to navigate through directories when resolving paths. `realpath()` does that once for all and remove the eventual trailing slashes

Answer (score 1):

Try "QMS/rev3/header.php" without the "/" at the begining

Comment: I just changed it to: require ("QMS/rev3/header.php"); and I get an error that says it "failed to open stream"

Comment: Ah I see what you mean now. I added the $SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'] at the beginning, the site comes up but still can't find my stylesheets and scripts

Answer (score 1):

If by removing the `/` from this line

`require $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'] . "/QMS/rev3/header.php";`

you manage to include the header.php file then you also need to change `$path` to:

`$path = $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'] . "QMS/rev3/";`

**In general** -  if you use a config.php to set your `$path` and you include it in all of your pages as you should, then use the `$path` variable and not `$_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'] . "QMS/rev3/`. This way you can mantain your code easily.

About the **NOT ALLOWED TO LOAD LOCAL RESOURCE**, take a look at **[this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20434624/not-allowed-to-load-local-resource-file)**

Comment: This is helpful but the main question here is that I get the error "NOT ALLOWED TO LOAD LOCAL RESOURCE". It is able to find the files, but will not load them due to some permissions error (probably through xampp).

Answer (score 1):

Do not use document_root for defining main path.
Put this line of code in your config.php

```
$path = rtrim(dirname(__file__),"/")."/";
```

Now your path variable has your root path including leading slash (/).
You can use this.

Answer (score 0):

After trying a lot of solutions
i made like this, because it's the way it work local and online.
You can define a variable with the path you need like this :

```
$path = "";
if ($_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'] == "localhost")
{
    $path = $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT']."/mysite";
}
else
{
    $path = $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'];
}

include_once($path.'/include/config.php');
```