# Build a bootstrap carousel with the php glob() function

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, wordpress, twitter-bootstrap

I'm desperately trying to build a home page with a slider , the problem is not the page itself but the fact that I would like to take image dynamically from a subfolder that i have created in the Wordpress uploads folder.
This is my code

```
<div id="" class="carousel slide" data-ride="carousel">

  <!-- Wrapper for slides -->
  <div class="carousel-inner" role="listbox">
    <?php
        $imageDir = "wp-content/uploads/home-carousel";
        $images = glob($imageDir.'/*.{jpg, jpeg, png, gif}');
        $flag=1;
        foreach ($images as $image){
        echo '<div class="item' .($flag?' active':''). '">';
        echo '<img src="'.$image.'" alt=""></div>';
        $flag=0;
        }
      ?>
  </div>

  <!-- Controls -->
  <a class="left carousel-control" href="#carousel-example-generic" role="button" data-slide="prev">
    <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-left" aria-hidden="true"></span>
    <span class="sr-only">Previous</span>
  </a>
  <a class="right carousel-control" href="#carousel-example-generic" role="button" data-slide="next">
    <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-right" aria-hidden="true"></span>
    <span class="sr-only">Next</span>
  </a>
</div>
```

the problem is that the glob() function returns me and empty array.
I also tried with this

```
<?php
        $imageDir = wp_upload_dir();
        $images = glob($imageDir['basedir'].'/home-carousel/*.{jpg, jpeg, png, gif}');
        $flag=1;
        foreach ($images as $image){
        echo '<div class="item' .($flag?' active':''). '">';
        echo '<img src="'.$image.'" alt=""></div>';
        $flag=0;
        }
      ?>
```

but is not working too.
can someone help me?
thanks!!!

Comment: Try the second arg `GLOB_BRACE `.

Answer (score 2):

Use `GLOB_BRACE`

```
$imageDir = wp_upload_dir();
$images = glob($imageDir['basedir'].'/home-carousel/*.{jpg, jpeg, png, gif}', GLOB_BRACE);
```

Comment: It works, but now the problem is that i'm not allowed to load local resource, this is the error message that i have in my console: 'Not allowed to load local resource: file:///C:/xampp/htdocs/spaziopsicoterapia/wp-content/uploads/home-carousel/imgres.jpg'

Comment: I think its due to the fact that PHP cannot access a file that is not on a server, without client permission.  check this answer http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21048976/php-xampp-server-document-root-folder-structure

Answer (score 1):

I finally arrived at the solution:

```
        <?php
            $images = glob('wp-content/uploads/home-carousel/*.{jpg, jpeg, png, gif}', GLOB_BRACE);
            $flag=1;
            foreach ($images as $image){
            echo '<div class="item' .($flag?' active':''). '">';
            echo '<img src="'.$image.'" alt=""></div>';
            $flag=0;
            }
         ?>
```